# Detect doubleclick on cell of TableView JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent, double-click

I am trying to detect a doubleclick on a random cell of a tableview.
The detection of the doubleclick is not a problem but rather which cell has been doubleclicked.

```
table.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if (event.getClickCount() > 1) {
                System.out.println("double clicked!");
                TableCell c =  (TableCell) event.getSource();
                System.out.println("Cell text: " + c.getText());
            }
        }
    });
```

This is how I'm building my table:

```
private void BuildTable() throws Exception
{
    /*Some initialisations etc*/

        for(int i=0; i<result.getMetaData().getColumnCount();i++)
        {
            final int j = i;
            TableColumn col = new TableColumn(result.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1));
            col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList,String>,ObservableValue<String>>(){
                public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param)
                {
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());
                }
            });
            table.getColumns().addAll(col);


        }
        while(result.next()){
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            for(int i = 1; i<=result.getMetaData().getColumnCount();i++){
                row.add(result.getString(i));
            }
            data.add(row);
        }
        table.setItems(data);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The real problem here is that I can't just typecast into a TableCell.
Can someone help me out? I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of registering a handler with the table,  you need to register the handler with the table cells themselves. To do this, use a cell factory on the appropriate `TableColumn`(s).

As an example, add the following code to the [standard table example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm#CJAGAAEE) (listing 13.6).

```
firstNameCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Person, String>, TableCell<Person, String>>() {
    @Override
    public TableCell<Person, String> call(TableColumn<Person, String> col) {
        final TableCell<Person, String> cell = new TableCell<Person, String>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(String firstName, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(firstName, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    setText(firstName);
                }
            }
         };
         cell.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
             @Override
             public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                 if (event.getClickCount() > 1) {
                     System.out.println("double click on "+cell.getItem());
                 }
             }
         });
         return cell ;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure if I'm implementing it the right way.
EDIT: I added the code of how I'm building my table

Comment: Looks fine to me. Just try adding the `cellFactory` to the columns when you create them, as well as the `cellValueFactory`.

Comment: Is it the same for JavaFX 8?

Comment: Thanks: it's now fixed. This code will work in Java 8, but you can replace the `Callback` implementation with a lambda expression, which reduces the complexity of the code.

Comment: Thanks . Is there any way to make the code work for both Double,String and Integer? This code will only work for String, as it has both defined string and the setText method.

Comment: Or if there is any simpler way. I just basically need the cell element, because I am showing a popup when the user clicks it.

Answer (score 0):

You need set the tableview's selection mode in cell, defined a custom type cell where you catch the keypress event or double clic, for an example you can review this page

https://gist.github.com/james-d/be5bbd6255a4640a5357