# how to make a custom listview having multiple text in javafx to dispay information

Tags: javafx

i need a custom listview in javafx, in that i want five textview in the item. this is a list of food orders which comes from the server using API and i have to display it in the listview. In one item there will be six text view for different six information like:
1. order id
2. order date and time
3. customer name
4. order type
5. payment status
6. total amount

Comment: That sounds like you really need a [`TableView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm#CJAGAAEE).

Comment: can i add click event on table item?

Comment: The same way as you do with a list: use a `cellFactory` and register handlers with the cells.

Comment: do you have an example of this thing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26563390/detect-doubleclick-on-row-of-tableview-javafx or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499269/javafx-tableview-detect-a-doubleclick-on-a-cell or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23998082/detect-doubleclick-on-cell-of-tableview-javafx or ...

Comment: hii.. can you please tell me .. how i pass a print job to a specific selected printer in my javafx application?

Comment: That has absolutely nothing to do with this question. Post a new question. You should include some code showing what you have tried. You might want to read up on how to use this site a little first: start with the [help] and maybe take the [tour].

Comment: yes i post new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35209455/how-pass-a-print-job-to-a-specific-printer-in-javafx-applcation

Comment: are you check my new post?